# How to create a dynamic search page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to javacript. I used an API for implementing custom search feature. But in my search page results show only after I enter the first search key. If I enter another search key, the results for the second key don't show up until I refresh the page.

How can I get the results to auto-update when entering more characters into the search box?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jsonData.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function display() {
          document.location = "contentpage.html";
      }
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#submit").click(searchAPI);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="search1"    >
    <button id="submit" >submit</button>
    <div id="div1">
        <img id="img" >
        <p id="desc">  </p>
        <p><a href="" target="_blank" id="link"></a></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS Code:

```
 function searchAPI(){
   var key= $("#search1").val();
   var htmlContent="<ul>";

   $.getJSON('http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=' + key + ' &format=json&pretty=1&callback=?', function(data) {
      var htmlContent = '<ul>';
      for (var i = 0; i < data.RelatedTopics.length; i++) {
          var desc = data.RelatedTopics[i].Text;
          var url = data.RelatedTopics[i].Icon.URL;
          var link = data.RelatedTopics[i].FirstURL;
          document.getElementById('link').href = link;
          var y = document.getElementById("link");
          y.innerHTML = link;
          htmlContent += "<li><img src='" + url + "' style='width:100px;height:100px;display:block'/> " +
          "<p id='desc'>" + desc + "</p>" + "<a target='_blank' id='link' href=" + link + " >go to website</a></li>";
      }
      htmlContent += "</ul>";
      $('#div1').html(htmlContent);
    });
 }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue...Thanks in advance.

Comment: When is `display()` called?

Comment: When user enter the search key and press submit

Comment: when user Enter Search key and submit,it calls SearchAPI(), the serachAPI() parse the json and returns the html page with data

Comment: So you are redirecting the user. Again, if you're calling `display()` when the user clicks the submit button, why do you have `$("#submit").click()` defined inside `$(document).ready(function(){}`? Can you elaborate where do you include the js code that you posted? Is it in an external js file or in the same page?

Comment: I updated the code, The above code is inside searchAPI() method, sorry i missed to post that

Comment: searchAPI() directly returns the HTML page with image and description

Comment: do you want the user to stay on the same page but the div showing the results should update on enter of a new letter as the search term

Comment: check this fiddle.     http://jsfiddle.net/sara_acid/Lr1o88nx/ 
It works there with your code. I dont get why and when you are using display().